# how to use microsoft speech api in building an engine for a new language

Tags: visual-c++, sapi

I want to develop a speech recognition software for hindi language. My problem is how to train the engine for some new language. But i am not able to find out how to add the speech database to the sapi. Also do i need to add grammer in speech recognition grammer specification? can there be any other better way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16851914/62576