# Google speech API integration into Voxcommando

Tags: speech-recognition

I am really really hope that somebody know the solution for the next:

I want to use the MS speech recognition with voxcommando (a speech recognizer), but with my own language (Hunagarian).

Unfortunatelly the langages pack does not include hungarian language pack.

Is it possble to..

use the Google hunagrian language pack or create in any way a hungarian language pack for the MS speech platform?

Thank you so much for every comment!!

Comment: If you implement SAPI 5 engine around Google API you'll be able to use it. It is not a trivial task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom SR (Speech Recognition) to Microsoft SAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851914/how-to-add-custom-sr-speech-recognition-to-microsoft-sapi)